# How do I open Python scripts using Sublime Text from terminal

Tags: python, sublimetext

Quick Question ! 
I want to change settings to open python files by default using Sublime Text when I open it from terminal.

> > $macbook: Open HelloWorld.py

It would be opened directly on Sublime Text without using vim to edit the files.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12249041/681182

Answer (score 4):

I linked it :  ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl

then run the command this way :

```
subl HelloWorld.py
```

Answer (score 1):

First create a symlink to Sublime then use it to open a file. Assuming your symlink is `sublime` it would be something like this:

```
sublime HelloWorld.py
```

More information [here](https://gist.github.com/olivierlacan/1195304) and [here](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/osx_command_line.html)

Comment: Yes! I tried this before I had this problem : -bash: sublime: command not found

Comment: Did you create the symlink?

Comment: Yes ! When I run  this: ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/sublime
ln: /usr/local/bin/sublime: File exists ..

Comment: It means that I created Symlink

Comment: Try running `which sublime` and post the output