# Set Visual Studio Code to be global Git editor on OSX

Tags: git, macos, visual-studio-code

I want to set VS Code to be my default git editor for commands such as rebase. This doesn't seem to be documented on the VS Code website. I've found a SO question about doing it for Windows, which sounds like it has mixed success: [How to use Visual Studio Code as Default Editor for Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30024353/how-to-use-visual-studio-code-as-default-editor-for-git)

Has anyone managed this on OSX?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<s>This is currently not possible with VS Code but planned for the future.</s>

**Update for our VS Code 1.0 release:**

This is now possible! All you need to do is to configure Code as the git editor using the newly introduced `--wait` option from the command line.

Answer (score 76):

***This work for me.***

> Install "code" from VSCode commander (Shift + Command + P)

Search for:

> Shell Command: Install 'code' command in 'PATH'

**Install it.**

after that… run commands on terminal for config git with new editor:

```
$ git config --global core.editor "code --wait"
$ git config --global -e
```

Answer (score 37):

Install "code" from VSCode commander(Shift + Command + P) 
[image]

then use these 2 lines in your terminal,

```
$ git config --global core.editor "code --wait"
$ git config --global -e
```

if you want to see local git config,

```
$ cd /path/to/git/repo/
$ git config -e
```

Answer (score 2):

Under **OS X El Capitan (10.11.4)** I was able to setup the whole thing:

1. Install Visual Code Studio on you OS X (make sure it's inside Applications folder `/Applications`)
2. Create a link with name `vscode` that links to your Visual Studio (inside Applications folder)using below command (be sure to use correct paths).

** If ~/bin folder doesn't exists, just create it:

> cd ~ && mkdir bin

If folder ~/bin exists just create a link:

> ln -s
>   /Applications/Visual\Studio\Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/code
>   ~/bin/vscode

3. Restart your terminal/shell and you should be able to open Visual Studio Code by typing `vscode` in terminal window.

> vscode

4. Visual Studio should open. If not and you have error. Add `~/bin/` to your PATH under OS X. Follows this ([How do I add ~/bin to my path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10767738/how-do-i-add-bin-to-my-path))
5. Edit global git config file with `~/.gitconfig` and set editor using `code` name. In my case it looks like this:

> [core]
>   editor = vscode --wait

OR type

> git config --global core.editor "vscode --wait"

[image]

6. Save file & restart terminal window. That's it!. Now you should be able enter commits descriptions using Visual Studio Code!